# problems for to save data in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

i´m learning node.js and i meeting with a problem, i want that when there is a method POST, the data is saved, when the server is running, the data is saved but when i turn off the server, the data is loss

```
const http = require('http')
const productos = require('./products')

const port = 3000 

http.createServer((req,res) => {
   req.on('error',err => {
       console.log(err)
       res.statusCode = 400
       res.end()
   })
   if(req.method === 'GET' && req.url === '/perro') {
       res.statusCode = 200
       res.setHeader('content-type','application/json')
       res.end(JSON.stringify(productos))

   } else if(req.method === 'POST' && req.url === '/perro') {
       res.statusCode = 200
       res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json')
       req.on('data',(chunk) => {
           const dato = JSON.parse(chunk)
           productos.push(dato)

            
       })
       res.end()  

   } else if(req.method === 'PUT' && req.url === '/perro') {
       res.statusCode = 200
       res.setHeader('content-type','application/json')

   }
   else {
       res.statusCode = 404
       res.on('error',(err) => {
           console.log(`El error es ${err}`);
       })

       res.end()
   }
}).listen(port,() => {
   console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
})
```

Comment: To persist state across server restarts you will need to save it to disk and then restore that when you load the server. You might want to look at NodeJS's `fs` module to save/read files or to look at a database.

Comment: It is just a piece of code, could you show the complete codes/project? I am not able to understand what the codes are doing.

Comment: @ChrisWong already is edited

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some storage (ex. database). Otherwise the data is saved to the memory, which is cleared if you restart your server

Comment: hello, the data is saved in a array, equal should saved at array ?, because i´m using the method Push

Comment: yes, and the array is stored in memory, and as a result - gets deleted on server restart.